# How can I index an array of objects in Javascript faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, autocomplete

In order to build the array of strings necessary for JQuery autocomplete, I'm traversing an array of objects and flattening it into an array of unique strings. I'm doing this about how you might expect:

```
var input = [{prop1:'value1', prop2: 'value2'}];

 $.each(input, function (index, value) {
                $.each(value, function (i, v) {
                    if (v != undefined && v != null && v != '' && ($.inArray(v, keywords) < 0)) {
                        keywords.push(v);
                    }
                });
            });
```

The problem is that it performs poorly for large `input` sets, and blocks the UI while it's running. How can I make this better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got an O(n^2) algorithm there.  Looking through that keywords array over and over again is going to get *really* slow (as you've noticed).

Instead, keep the keywords as an object:

```
var keywords = {};

    // ... inside your ".each():
    if (v && !keywords[v])
      keywords[v] = true;
```

Note that your tests of "v" against undefined, null, and the empty string can be replaced by letting JavaScript check it's truthiness. That's not *always* the right thing, but it's fine here.

You can *also* keep the keywords in an array, if you like.  Just don't search the array to determine whether a keyword has been seen yet.

Comment: +1 it should be noted that arrays and objects are handled internally the same way by Javascript. This way at least the engine does the uniqueness checking instead of your code. But the performance of `keywords[100]` and `keywords['some-string']` for an array and an object with the same numbers of properties/elements is probably similar.

Comment: Well yes, but that's not really the point - the key is to index by the string itself, to take advantage of the fast hashtable implementation internal to the JavaScript runtime.

Comment: Right, I agree. I just wanted to point out that there's not really a downside to doing this (e.g. arrays are not a faster storage mechanism than objects anyway). Intuitively, one would expect array access by index to be faster than objects by key, but it's not the case. So in some situations a programmer may think they should use an array (because later access would be by numeric index). Interestingly a quick test I set up shows objects FASTER than arrays for like uses: http://jsperf.com/array-vs-object-jamie

Comment: Whoah - just ran that test in firefox. Results COMPLETELY different - arrays more than 10 times faster. And both results faster than Chrome. That is unexpected. Firefox must optimize arrays in some way. Interesting. Test probably not perfect though (as I create a variable def in the loop).

Comment: I get the same results. That's pretty amazing.

Comment: If that result is correct (for what I'm trying to test for) it would make a huge performance difference in firefox for data-intensive applications designed properly. I have a feeling my test is flawed (e.g. perhaps FF just caches the last value accessed and chrome doesn't). Would probably need to design a better test to be sure, but it sure it sure is interesting.

Answer (score 2):

i think you're trying to fix wrong problem

why is your autosuggestion list so big that javascript performs poorly? just send top 10 autosuggestions to client and you'll be fine

Comment: I'm creating an UI widget that has a built-in autocomplete. I don't want developers to have to create a specialized indexing service just to generate the autocomplete data.

Comment: so what should developer do if he has 10 millions of records with data that has to be suggested by autocomplete widget?

Comment: set `{automcomplete:false}` in my widget and use their own solution. This will work for the vast majority of cases, assuming I can get the performance I want...